# read data from exising secret code

Tags: android

I want to read data from existing secret code. there are plenty of secret code in android like `*#*#4636#*#*` to get phone info and `*#06#`to get IMEI.

so there any way in android to write a code by which we can fire these secret code and read the result back in our activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik No, you cannot run those "secret" codes and get the result in your activity. Because, these codes need to be dialed in and then only the results come in. Even if you are able to dial these codes, you wont be able to get the output in your activity for sure.
But there are other many ways through which you can get the data that you need programmatically. For instance, for IMEI number you can use [getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)

```
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()
```

This requires the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

(Be careful with the above permission as users will wonder as to why your application needs to access the telephony stack)
To get other details like the manufacture, OS, etc take a look at [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) and [System](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html). You can use the following codes

```
android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER      // Manufacturer
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT
```

A simple and efficient code to get the device full name for all types of manufacturers and devices is as follows.

```
public String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}


private String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
    }
}
```